# Using Iteration in Battle'tanks' Simulation MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement, while-loop, iteration

Round three: Jessica vs Battletanks

**tl;dr:
Right now, I need help making my dimensions match. My function flags me at "if attacked == 0"
What I am trying to make it do is read if the value at that location is a zero or not. If it's a zero, then there is no ship there, so it's a 'miss'. If there is a number there (4, 3,2 or 1) then it's a hit.

Basically what I need to do for this next problem is figure out how to write a function that simulates a game of battletanks (or battleship).

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game) in case you've never played
```

In this function, I feed in three inputs: two arrays of tank locations (so player1 and player2) and a string of the moves made (they are all separated by a space). The field is an 8x8 array and the moves are indicated by strings such as 'A7 H6' etc etc. A7 means to hit the spot at column 1, row 6. 'H6' means to hit column 8, row 6. I have to reflect that in my function.

What I need to output is: the array of the victor's tanks, a vector that details the winner's hits(in order they were made) and a vector displaying the winner (or the string 'Cease Fire!')

```
function[winner_field, winner_hits, tanks_destroyed] = battleTanks(player1_tanks, player2_tanks, battle_str)
```

There are four types of tanks in the game:
Heavy tanks are represented by the number '4' and are 3x2

Medium tanks are represented by the number '3' are are 2x2

Light tanks are represented by the number '1' are a 2x1

Tank destroyers are represented by the number '2' and are 3x1

Empty spaces are represented by a '0'

Note:Tanks can be aligned vertically or horizontally

The first player always makes the first move, and it alternates

Not all tanks have to be played, however if you only play one tank and it gets destroyed, you lose

I need to keep track of the order where ships get hit, and then which ones get destroyed

You can make the same move over again

In my output arrays, any place where a tank has been hit but not destroyed should be represented by a 0. So there may be "jagged tanks"

How to win:

If a player destroys all of the player's tanks, they win

If neither side has lost all their tanks after all moves have been played, the winner is determined by the number of hits scored on the enemy fleet (NOT the number of tanks they destroyed).

There can be a tie, in which case In the event of this, the outputs of the function will become the secondary outputs 1) the 1st players final 8x8 array, 2) the 2nd players final 8x8 array, and 3) a string, 'Cease fire!'.

I apologize in advance for the length of the question, and my code.

```
function[winner_field, winner_hits, tanks_destroyed] = battleTanks(player1_tanks, player2_tanks, battle_str)
player1_moves = mod(battle_str, 2) == 1;
player2_moves = mod(battle_str, 2) == 0; %// Player 2 is the even moves

[player1_moves, player2_moves] = strtok(battle_str);
player2_moves = char(player2_moves);
player1_moves = char(player1_moves);

column = upper(player1_moves(1)) - 64; 
row = player1_moves(2) - 48; %// Does the conversion so my funciton knows that A7 means column 1,     row 7

attacked = find(player1_moves);
attacked2 = find(player2_moves);

winner_hits = []; %// Empty vector to populate with answers
tanks_destroyed = []; %// Same as above

Counter1 = 0; %// My counter for hits, just in case they both run out of moves before finishing
Counter2 = 0;

Tanks_destroyed1 = 0; %// Counts how many tanks are destroyed by player 1
Tanks_destroyed2 = 0;

heavy_tank1 = find(player1_tanks, 4); %// locates the tanks
heavy_tank2 = find(player2_tanks, 4);
medium_tank1 = find(player1_tanks, 3);
medium_tank2 = find(player2_tanks, 3);
tank_destroyer1 = find(player1_tanks, 2);
tank_destroyer2 = find(player2_tanks, 2);
light_tank1 = find(player1_tanks, 1);
light_tank2 = find(player2_tanks, 1);

if attacked == 0  %// If they hit a zero, it counts as a mis
    attack = 'missed';
else
    attack = 'hit'; %// if they find a number, they hit a tank
   end

hit = 'hit'; %// Translates the string into a variable I can use
missed = 'missed';

if attacked == hit %// Does the counter
    Counter1 = Counter1 + 1;
elseif attacked2 == hit
    Counter2 = Counter2 + 1;
else
    Counter1 = Counter1 + 0;
    end

for field = 1:length(player1_tanks)
    if heavy_tank1 == 6 %// Counts the destroyed tanks
        tank = 'destroyed';
    Tanks_destroyed2 = Tanks_destroyed2 + 1;
elseif tank_destroyer1 == 3
    tank = 'destroyed';
    Tanks_destroyed2 = Tanks_destroyed2 + 1;
elseif medium_tank1 == 4
    tank = 'destroyed';
    Tanks_destroyed2 = Tanks_destroyed2 + 1;
elseif light_tank1 == 2
    tank = 'destroyed';
    Tanks_destroyed2 = Tanks_destroyed2 + 1;
else
    tank = 'missed';

end
end
for field = 1:length(player2_tanks)
 if heavy_tank2 == 6
    tank = 'destroyed';
    Tanks_destroyed1 = Tanks_destroyed1 + 1;
elseif tank_destroyer2 == 3
    tank = 'destroyed';
    Tanks_destroyed1 = Tanks_destroyed1 + 1;
elseif medium_tank2 == 4
    tank = 'destroyed';
    Tanks_destroyed1 = Tanks_destroyed1 + 1;
elseif light_tank2 == 2
    tank = 'destroyed';
    Tanks_destroyed1 = Tanks_destroyed1 + 1;
 else
     tank = 'missed';

 end
end

if Tanks_destroyed1 == player2_tanks %// Determines the winner
    winner_field = player1_tanks;
elseif Tanks_destroyed2 == player1_tanks
    winner_field = player2_tanks;
elseif Counter1 > Counter2
    winner_field = player1_tanks;
elseif Counter2 > Counter1
    winner_field = player2_tanks;
else
    winner_field = 'Cease Fire!';

end
if winner_field == player1_tanks
    winner_hits = hits;

end

end
```

This code is really killing my wrists, so I apologize for others who wrists may be hurt. Though I am probably over complicating it.

```
Testcases
[results1, winHits1, winDestroy1] = battleTanks(battleAP1,battleAP2,moveA)
 results1 should be the same as resultsA (which is saved in battleTanks.mat)
 winHits1 = [1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3]
 winDestroy1 = [1 2 3]
```

battleAP1, battleAP2 and moveA are all files include with the HW problem. I'm going to try and access them to get out their information.

So what I need help with basically is figuring out how to format my output statements and making the function realize that A = column 1.

```
battleAP1:
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   3   3   0   0   0
0   2   0   3   3   0   0   0
0   2   0   4   4   4   0   0
0   2   0   4   4   4   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
battleAP2
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   3   3   0
0   0   4   4   0   3   3   0
0   0   4   4   0   0   0   0
0   0   4   4   2   2   2   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0
MoveA: 'A5 H7 C3 G1 D3 F7 G6 C2 H6 D4 G7 H2 G8 H4 E5 D8 F6 B6 E6 A5 F5 G2 H3'
```

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit confused! What is not working? or what are you struggling wiht?

Comment: Technically the whole problem. I hit the 'submit' button a little early, my apologies. I am not entirely sure how to set-up my outputs and I feel like I need a while loop, but I'm unsure how to go about it.

Comment: You have to encapsulate your problem better. Ain't nobody got time to debug an entire program. You'll get a lot more help if you say exactly what should be happening at 1 step, and you're seeing instead.

Comment: I agree with @EugeneK.  Though we are here to help you, you are asking us to debug your entire program.  I don't have time for that either :(  Can you narrow it down to what exactly you need help with?  I haven't read the entire post myself, but it's a bit intimidating.

Comment: It's an intimidating problem. Right now my main struggle is formatting the outputs and figuring out how to make the function realize A7 means column1, row7.

Comment: @JessicaMarie - If you can, please provide sample inputs and outputs.  I'm having a bit of trouble determining how the inputs are shaped.

Comment: @rayryeng I finally got the input cell-thing to open. It didn't like me earlier. I'm starting to think engineering isn't my thing, since technology doesn't seem to be my friend.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your particular question in the comments, if I have an input `A7` and I want to convert it to a set of indices, one way to do this is to split it up and then subtract the ASCII offset. Google ASCII table if you don't understand the numbers I'm using. Basically when you do match with a char and a number in matlab, it automatically converts the char to its ASCII number.

```
input = 'A7';
column = upper(input(1)) - 64; %upper guarantees that my letter will be upper case
row = input(2) - 48;
```

Comment: This is what I would have suggested.   +1.  Another way to be more robust if you don't remember what the ASCII code for `A` is, is to subtract with `double('A')`.  In other words:  `column = upper(input(1)) - double('A');`.  Also, something minor: `input` is a pre-defined function in MATLAB.  You may want to change the name to another variable so you don't unintentionally shadow over the function.

Comment: That makes sense. I almost forgot about ASCII values.

Comment: @JessicaMarie - How could you :P!  It was in your very first post you've put here :)

Comment: I try to forget things that keep my brain up at night. It's bad for cognition and norepinephrine/erpinephrine levels :)